# Read data from AWS S3 using pyspark and python. (Read All columns: Partioned column also)

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-data-wrangler

I have saved the spark dataframe to AWS S3 in Parquet format partitionby column "channel_name".
Below code is how i saved to S3:

```
df.write.option("header",True) \
        .partitionBy("channel_name") \
        .mode("overwrite") \
        .parquet("s3://path/")
```

| channel_name | start_timestamp | value | Outlier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEMP | 2021-07-19 07:27:51 | 21 | false |
| TEMP | 2021-07-19 08:21:05 | 24 | false |
| Vel | 2021-07-19 08:20:18 | 22 | false |
| Vel | 2021-07-19 08:21:54 | 26 | false |
| TEMP | 2021-07-19 08:21:23 | 25 | false |
| TEMP | 2021-07-16 08:22:41 | 88 | false |

As it was partitionby "channel_name",Now while reading the same data from S3 it is missing that column "channel_name". below is my code for pyspark and for python.

```
df = spark.read.parquet("s3://Path/") #spark
```

for Python i am using AWS wrangler:

```
import awswrangler as wr

df = wr.s3.read_parquet(path="s3://Path/")
```

This is how df looks like without column "channel_name".

| start_timestamp | value | Outlier |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-19 07:27:51 | 21 | false |
| 2021-07-19 08:21:05 | 24 | false |
| 2021-07-19 08:20:18 | 22 | false |
| 2021-07-19 08:21:54 | 26 | false |
| 2021-07-19 08:21:23 | 25 | false |
| 2021-07-16 08:22:41 | 88 | false |

How to read complete data including partition column, please let me know if there any alternative.